# zfs: replace a disk NON-mirrored pool with one disk

Tags: zfs

I have 2 disk (1tb each) pool. I'd like to replace it with a larger disk (2tb)

I was not able to find a simple command like "replace" that can work in this situation.
Any help will be appreciated. If I use send/receive. It will create a new pool.

zpool status -v backup:

```
  pool: backup
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 0 days 00:33:35 with 0 errors on Sun Oct 11 00:57:36 2020
config:

    NAME                                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    backup                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
      ata-SanDisk_SD8SN8U1T001122_161016440716  ONLINE       0     0     0
      ata-Crucial_CT1050MX300SSD4_163713E82203  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new pool on the new disk and zfs send/receive to the new pool.